# Using ant, Fail if the file contains "SUCCESS" string

Tags: ant

Basically I want to check if the file contains "SUCCESS" string. If string not found then ant has to exit with error message.
Please help me on this.
I tried many links but did'nt get this answer

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can do this with the Ant [`fail` task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/fail.html), assuming the file to check is called `log.txt`:

```
<fail message="SUCCESS Found...failing">
    <condition>
        <resourcecontains resource="log.txt" substring="SUCCESS"/>
    </condition>
</fail>
```

Here's an alternative approach, that you could adapt if you have more than one file to check.

```
<fileset id="success.file" dir="." includes="log.txt">
    <contains text="SUCCESS"/>
</fileset>
<fail message="SUCCESS Found...failing">
    <condition>
        <resourcecount when="greater" count="0" refid="success.file" />
    </condition>
</fail>
```

If none of the files in the fileset contain the string 'SUCCESS' then the fileset will be empty, so the build will not fail.

Comment: which is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374137/using-ant-check-if-a-particular-string-is-found-in-a-file, link in my answer

Comment: @David Isn't this somewhat different?  There's no mention of FTP/get in this question, so it's simpler.

Comment: @martin clayton Sure, but the actual solution, i.e. using resourcecontains, is the same, no ?

Comment: @David - I guess so, but this question is sufficiently different that a separate answer seems warranted.

Comment: @martin fair enough, your answer is well detailed too, so it deserves being accepted by sree

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Linux, you could simply wrap the [Get](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_GET.htm) command with the [exec](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html) target in Ant

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4374137/using-ant-check-if-a-particular-string-is-found-in-a-file) could also be useful

Comment: David, I was looking for a platform independent solution. Thanks for your point also.