# How to search for a file content using ant script?

Tags: ant

My requirement is to search for a "String" in a file and if the string is present in the file then I want to zip the folder else nothing to be zipped.
Could any one please throw idea on how I could start with?

I attempted to find the required ant task, but could not get it.

Thanks,
Kishore

Comment: [zip](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/zip.html), [contains](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html#contains) and [loadfile](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/loadfile.html) tasks may help you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using ant, Fail if the file contains "SUCCESS" string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4722803/using-ant-fail-if-the-file-contains-success-string)

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4302019/how-to-search-for-a-string-in-files-with-ant-make-sure-certain-string-isnt-fou/44709739